# sending an email with sendgrid and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, sendgrid

I would like to send an email to myself(outlook adress) using sendgrid.
I have added a sender authentification for my email adress ( the same i use in send grid message: to and from parameters)
Inside an express node server, i process the mail transport. see the code below.

```
app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
        to: 'The email i have register as sender authentification',
        from: 'The email i have register as sender authentification',
        subject: 'information request with same from and to',
        text: 'Hello i am ' + req.body.name + req.body.informationDetails
    };

    sendGrid.send(msg)
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200)
        res.json({
            success: true
        });

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
        res.status(401).json({
            success: false
        });

    })
});
```

The sendgrid activity page shows me that the mails have been delivered to the adress i have register but i am unable to receive the email inside my mailbox.
i am little lost on how to solve that

Moreover, in the frontend, i am using axios to connect the backend to send the request parameters, but the res value cant be displayed.

```
Axios.post('/api/email', this.state)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("check before if success");
            console.log(res);
            if(res.data.success) {
                this.setState({
                    name: "",
                    phoneNumber: "",
                    informationDetails: "",
                    disabled: false
                });
            } else {
                console.log("no success");
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    disabled: false
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                disabled: false
            });
        })
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: May be it is going to the junk folder... Try to use this api through postman and see if you get any email. If you still dont get any email then its not your code, its their ApI which is not working.... Also place a console.log inside the if check if(res.data.success) and see if you are really getting a success from the call.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether you have solved it or not. but i have a working example following your problem. i won't be explaining it to you because of not being sure of executing it futher.

**nodejs:**

```
app.post("/contact", (req,res,next) => {
  
const name = req.body.name;
const email = req.body.email;
const subject=req.body.subject;
const message = req.body.message;
  const msg = {
   to: "it's ur desired email", //receiver's email
    from: email, // Change to your verified sender
    subject: subject,
    text: "testing from local",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p> sends a message from <p>Email: ${email}</p>: <br/><p>Message: ${message}</p>`,

  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then((result) => {
      res.json({success: true});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json("Error")
    });
```

**App.js from frontend:**

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/contact', this.state)
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data.success) {
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: true
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);

                this.setState({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
            })

    }
```

i have added the subject area because i needed it for my project and it looks cool for me.

let me know if it works

Comment: It would help to know what this.state was in the second code block.